# Wordpress get post date

Tags: php, wordpress, date, post

I am using shortcode to display blogroll on my main static page.

It displays title and up to N characters of the excerpt.

However, I have no idea how can I get post date to show up next to the title.

Is get_the_date function the correct one to use? How to implement it?
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date

```
<?php

function getblogposts($atts, $content = null) {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'posts' => 1,
   ), $atts));

   $return_string = '<h3>'.$content.'</h3>';
   $return_string .= '<ul>';
   query_posts(array('orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' , 'showposts' => $posts));
   if (have_posts()) :
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $return_string .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
    $return_string .= '<div class="excerpt">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</div></li>';
endwhile;
   endif;
   $return_string .= '</ul>';

   wp_reset_query();
   return $return_string;
}
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return ' <a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">Continue reading</a>';
}   
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );  


function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 100 );
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You could use `get_the_date()`. The important thing is use it within the loop (between `while(have_posts()` and `endwhile;`.

You could use

```
echo get_the_date();
```

OR

```
the_date(); //without echo
```

Another thing that you really really should consider is to NOT use query_posts().  Why? It's not easy to answer (it basically could mess up other queries), but take a look at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts.

Comment: Ok it solved the data issues. However I am not sure how to implement pre_get_posts instead of query_posts(). Could you help me out with this?

Comment: There are some examples in the link I supplied. Try to use WP_Query-example which is slightly easier to understand if you're just learning.

Answer (score 0):

```
$post_date = get_the_date('l,d');
```